# Pass the index of a for loop to a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

What is the way to pass the 'i' of a for loop to a different function?
I need to get a click function that changes the left position of a <ul> but in each click it must use the values stored in an array according by its index position.

```
var currentPosition = new Array();

// store some values in an array
function slide() {
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var positions = 100 * j;
    currentPosition.push(positions);
    function moveIt(j);
  }
}

function moveIt(j) {
  $(document).on('click','#left', function() {
    $('ul').animate({'left': currentPosition[j]  + 'px'});
  })   
}

slide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/gTQ3M/1/

Comment: I don't see an `i`, but I see a `j`. Can you please clarify? You say you need to pass an `i`, but there is none.

Comment: Nevermind, @gdoron just answered your question, (and mine) I think :)

Comment: Excuse me, I was moving my code to the fiddle and ommited to replace the j with i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function slide() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var positions = 100 * j;
    currentPosition.push(positions);
    //function moveIt(j); <=================== delete this.
        moveIt(j); //<======================== Change to this.
  }
}
```

[**Yours updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTQ3M/4/)

Comment: Put a var in front of the ```j = 0``` to avoid creating a global variable.

Comment: @TJVanToll - I think he just fixed the problem, so you could probably remove the downvote, considering this is an awesome answer. +1

Comment: @gdoron - I was thinking the same :)  Not sure why though... maybe the events register like a closure. Closures are something that I can use when I need them, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around exactly when and when not to use them.

Comment: @jmort253. It's because he's calling the function **inside** the loop, not storing it and using it **after** the loop.

Comment: @gdoron - Still, this is one where I'll have to think about it for awhile until that aha moment. It's obviously correct though. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Great answer, I'll take it as the correct answer, but I have a different question. How can I stop the animation for only a single index?

Comment: @Cadence96 - Either include an if condition in your click handler for cases where you don't want animation, or don't register the animation click event for the items you're precognitive about wanting to exclude.

Comment: It looks like you took out the closure, but I'm pretty sure that closures are never necessary when all you're doing is calling an external function.

Comment: @Cadence96. What do you mean by _"stop for a single index"_?

Comment: @gdoron I mean to make the animation run just once, and not to run all values in the array.

Comment: @Cadence96. Call the animation function in the end. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTQ3M/5/)

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `function` keyword in the last line of the loop

```
var positions = 100 * j; 
currentPosition.push(positions); 
function moveIt(j);
```

like so

```
var positions = 100 * j; 
currentPosition.push(positions); 
moveIt(j);
```

Comment: Peter - I didn't downvote this, but I think he was asking how to lock the `j` inside the event he's registering inside the moveIt function. The `j` is constantly changing and won't be the same when that event fires, unless of course it's locked away safely in a closure... unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Actually, the error was in his fiddle, and this appears to do the same thing gdoron's answer is doing. So +1 to you sir.